# Cannot convert System.Threading.Tasks.Task... to System.Threading.Tasks.Task... despite seemingly being same type

Tags: c#, multithreading, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting a strange error in Rider eluding to the fact that I am trying to convert to a Task in a way that's not allowed. The odd part is that the types seem to be an exact match.

**Code throwing error**

```
        public IEnumerator GetCatalogItem_LevelDataId_PlayFabCatalogItemFound(string levelName,long levelDataId)
        {
            //Arrange
            const string getCatalogItemCloudFunctionName = "getCatalogItem";
            var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"itemId", levelDataId.ToString()}
            };
            //Act
            var result = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance
                .GetHttpsCallable(getCatalogItemCloudFunctionName)
                .CallAsync(data);
            //BUG ERROR IS SHOWN ON result BELOW (SEE ATTACHED IMAGE)
            yield return result.AsIEnumerator<HttpsCallableResult>();
            var catalogItem = (IDictionary)result.Result.Data;
            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(levelName,catalogItem["DisplayName"].ToString());
        }
```

**Task Extention Method Used**

```
    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a <see cref="System.Threading.Tasks.Task"/> to <see cref="IEnumerator"/> (helps with unity coroutines)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">The task to convert</param>
        /// <returns>An IEnumerator which waits till the task has been completed</returns>
        public static IEnumerator AsIEnumerator(this Task task)
        {
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                throw task.Exception;
            }
        }
        
        /// <inheritdoc cref="AsIEnumerator"/>
        public static IEnumerator AsIEnumerator<T>(this Task<T> task)
        {
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                throw task.Exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error Thrown**

> Cannot convert instance argument type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableResult> [Firebase.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Firebase.Functions.HttpsCallableResult> [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'

[Task Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myy1t.png)

Comment: One is from Firebase.Functions, another from mscorlib.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase comes with its own implementation of `Task` and `Task<T>` according to their documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/system/threading/tasks/task

Looks like you'll need to make which one is used more explicit in your code so the correct one is resolved as the reference you wish to use.